# In WinNT.h, why are STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ, ...WRITE and ...EXECUTE defined to be the same?

Tags: c++, winapi

I was doing some Win32 interop. stuff and, while searching headers and perusing the MSDN and defining constants and dll-imports in a happy bubble, I spotted some odd lines in WinNT.h (lines 6486-6488 in my version... er... 7.1a, I think)

```
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ             (READ_CONTROL)
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE            (READ_CONTROL)
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE          (READ_CONTROL)
```

I stared at this for a while, sipping my tea, wondering why these three constants are all defined to be the same value.

It's intriguing. Does anyone know?

Comment: good question. this is something i questioned myself for a long time!

Answer (score 2):

Different types of kernel object have different pre-defined access masks for reading, writing, and executing.

For example, tokens use `TOKEN_READ`, `TOKEN_WRITE` and `TOKEN_EXECUTE`.  Files use `FILE_GENERIC_READ`, `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` and `FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE`:

Compare the definitions of `TOKEN_READ` and `FILE_GENERIC_READ`:

```
#define TOKEN_READ       (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ      |\
                          TOKEN_QUERY)

#define FILE_GENERIC_READ         (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ     |\
                                   FILE_READ_DATA           |\
                                   FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES     |\
                                   FILE_READ_EA             |\
                                   SYNCHRONIZE)
```

`STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ` is the set of standard access rights that need to appear in an object-type-specific access mask for reading.  Similarly for `STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE` and `STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE`.

It happens to be the case that the standard access right you need for reading, writing and executing is `READ_CONTROL`, so `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ`, `STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE` and `STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE` are all defined as that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment in header and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights) that you skipped:

> These are **currently** defined to READ_CONTROL

I believe it answers your question.
They planned to implement different sets of standard rights but didn't make progress still.

Raymond Chen in his New Old Thing blog and book gives many examples of such dead code in Windows (planned features, ideas not happened to be implemented). Although he hasn't covered `STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE` and `READ_CONTROL` yet I think this is the same case.